# How add to `pod_target_xcconfig` more flags?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I have [podspec](https://github.com/ivanvorobei/SPPermissions/blob/main/SPPermissions.podspec) file and using `pod_target_xcconfig`.
Now I added only one flag:

```
"SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS"  => "SPPERMISSIONS_CAMERA"
```

How I can add more flags? I mean syntax.

Maybe:

```
"SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS"  => "SPPERMISSIONS_CAMERA, SECOND_FLAG"
"SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS"  => "SPPERMISSIONS_CAMERA", "SECOND_FLAG"
"SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS"  => "SPPERMISSIONS_CAMERA" + "SECOND_FLAG"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the values with a space:

```rb
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { "SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS"  => "SPPERMISSIONS_CAMERA SECOND_FLAG" }
```